# using document.write("<img and 'array[0]' together

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, document.write

I've got stuck, some help would be much appreciated…

I'm using xml like a mini database, I've got php creating an array of images from the xml file, all this works fine. I want to use some of those images as part of this nice jquery zoom thingy > http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Here's where I'm at:

```
document.write("<img id='zoom_01' src=" + "../../shop/e20_portal/" + imagelist_s_array[0] + "' data-zoom-image='../../shop/e20_portal/" + imagelist_l_array[0] + "'/>");
```

both these correctly spit out the right url, EG:'e20_s.jpg' but the above code doesn't work.

```
imagelist_s_array[0]
imagelist_l_array[0]
```

Comment: Define doesn't work. Are there errors in your javascript console? Is that string being written to the DOM?

Comment: No image is shown in firefox, broken image in chrome, both display the correct url in their inspectors. Firebug dosnt show any errors (thanks for not hating me for using document.write as seems to be the way here)

Comment: Well, there are better ways than using `document.write()`. That aside, if you put the image `src` directly into your browser, can you actually see the image?

Comment: If I type the url by hand within the document.write it works, yea

Comment: (It might be difficult at this point for me to use something else other than doucment.write, but I'm interested to know what other ways of doing this kind of thing there are so I can avoid it in the future)

Comment: That isn't what I am asking. If you copy->paste the `src` onto the end of your browser request, does that image show up?

Comment: If I type '../../shop/e20_portal/e20_l.jpg' it works. If I type the full thing into a browser, the image shows, yea

Comment: I've pored over it and it seems to be working now. There might have been in an issue with having '' instead of " somewhere. Justin, Thanks for the help, whatever you said worked

Answer (score 0):

> If I type the url by hand within the document.write it works.
>
> If I type '../../shop/e20_portal/e20_l.jpg' it works. If I type the full thing into a browser, the image shows, yea
>
> There might have been in an issue with having '' instead of " somewhere.